# Lambda expression for comparing multiple fields using C++ sort

Tags: c++, sorting, lambda, compare

I want to sort a vector, which's element is an object including three fields.

I can compare one field  by the following code,

```
    std::sort(std::execution::par, pidx.begin(), pidx.end(), [&P](int i, int j) { 
        return P[i].obj[0]<P[j].obj[0];
        }
    );
```

But when comparing multiple fields, it failed with a runtime error.

```
    std::sort(std::execution::par, pidx.begin(), pidx.end(), [&P](int i, int j) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            if (P[i].obj[k] < P[j].obj[k])
                return true;
        return false;
        }
    );
```

Runtime error as the following,

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> File C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.22910\inclue\xutility
>
> Line:1626
>
> Expression: invalid comparator
>
> For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the visual C++ documentation on asserts.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is `P`? What is e.g. `P[i]`? What is `P[i].obj`? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: Sorry for unclear information. P is a vector of objects. P[i] and P[j]  are two elements of P. pidx is another integer vector, which stores the index of the P element.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution, the comparison lambda function is not correct.

```
    std::sort(std::execution::par, pidx.begin(), pidx.end(), [&P](int i, int j) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            if (P[i].obj[k] != P[j].obj[k])
                return P[i].obj[k] < P[j].obj[k];
        return false;
        }
    );
```

Comment: `return P[i].obj < P[j].obj;` might be enough.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  In my case, the obj(s) are stored in an pure array but not vector, so I have to compare them in sequence. I will try your method in the future program.

Comment: You might use `std::array` instead of C-array, or use [`std::lexicographical_compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare).